# kotlin random images without repetition in other imageviews

Tags: android, image, kotlin, duplicates, imageview

how can I solve in kotlin, I am about to finish an app but I can't close everything?

the function that I am not good at

the fact is that with three imageviews I would like the image in imageview not to repeat the same figure in imageview 2 and 3 so I would like the list to be one and that there are no duplicates to show between the three imageviews here is the code:

```
 private lateinit var listId: List<Int>
 
 initializeList()
 
 pickNumber ()

    }

    private fun pickNumber (){
        binding.imageView.setImageResource(listId.random())
        binding.imageView2.setImageResource(listId.random())
        binding.imageView3.setImageResource(listId.random())
        
        
         private fun initializeList() {
        listId = listOf(
            R.drawable.we ,
            R.drawable.wq,
            R.drawable.set,
            R.drawable.opt,
            R.drawable.ups,
        )
```

with 80 images

Comment: One option is to shuffle the list (`list.shuffle()`) and then get element 0, 1, 2, etc.

Comment: can I have a key for a result of what I show?maybe even in another key that leads to a different screen to implement a text

Comment: @gpunto how can I put fixed text for each changing image in a random image list? in kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As gpunto suggested, you can shuffle the list first and then fetch elements one by one.

```kotlin
private fun pickNumber (){
    val (id1, id2, id3) = list.shuffled()  
    binding.imageView.setImageResource(id1)
    binding.imageView2.setImageResource(id2)
    binding.imageView3.setImageResource(id3)
}
```

Here I used [list destructuring](https://tedblob.com/kotlin-destructuring-list/) to get first three elements of the list.

[Official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html)

Comment: it worked, thanks to both of you you were fantastic, I think this will help many people, who like me have had the same problem, thanks for everything

Comment: private fun pickNumber (){
        val (id1, id2, id3) = listId.shuffled()
        binding.imageView.setImageResource(id1)
        binding.imageView2.setImageResource(id2)
        binding.imageView3.setImageResource(id3)

Comment: how can I take the result and change the screen to get a description? I would like to do it with a key that appears after getting the result @Arpit Shukla

Comment: This seems to be a somewhat different question. You can ask a separate question for this providing more context about it.

Comment: ok, this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72425001/kotlin-how-to-implement-an-image-description-r-drawable-in-imageview-set-in-sh